# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{k = 0}^n q^k \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to understand the asymptotic behavior of $$\sum_{k = 0}^n q^k \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!}$$ when $n \to \infty$, depending of $q > 0$.

I did numerical simulations and apparently $$\sum_{k = 0}^n 3^{n -k} \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!} \to 0$$ whereas

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n (3/2)^{n -k} \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!} \to \infty$$

I tried to used a kind of Stirling formula: $$\frac{n^n}{e^{n -1}} \leq n! \leq \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}$$ but with no sucess.

Do you have any hint?

I am interested in something like : for $q$ big enough, there is a "simple" expression $\epsilon_n \to 0$ such that:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n q^{n -k} \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!} \leq \epsilon_n$$

For the context, I am tryig to understand the "size" of the expansion of $A^k f$ where $f$ is a smooth function and $A(g)(x) = x g(x) - g'(x)$. By using a non commutative binomial expansion, this kind of sum appears.

Comment: It seems that your first formula should have $q^{n-k}$ instead of $q^k$ ,right?

Comment: It can be with $q^k$, $q^{-k}$ (q or 1/q) or $q^{n-k}$ (mutiply everything by $q^n$).  I should have write the results of the simulations as $q^n \times \sum\dots \to 0$.

Comment: what is exactly the term $\sqrt{(2n)!}$? for example for $n=10$ is it $(20!)^{1/2}$ or $(20^{1/2})!$?

Comment: It is $(20!)^{1/2}$.

Comment: To understand the asymptotic behavior of the sum as $n \to \infty$, it is helpful to consider the ratio of consecutive terms in the sum:

$$\frac{q^{k+1} \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2(k+1))!((n-k)-1)!}}{q^k \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n-k)!}} = \frac{q(n-k)}{(2(k+1))}$$

As $n \to \infty$, the ratio approaches 0 if $q < 1$, and approaches infinity if $q > 1$. This suggests that the sum will converge if $q < 1$, and diverge if $q > 1$.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. k is between 1 and n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote
$$S(q,n)=\sum_{k = 0}^n q^k \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!}.$$
This sum can be expressed in terms of the Kummer $U$-function as follows:
$$
S(q,n)  = ( - 1)^n \frac{{4^n }}{{\sqrt {(2n)!} }}U\!\left( { - n,\frac{1}{2},\frac{q}{4}{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} } \right)
$$
(see, e.g., [$(13.2.7)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E7)). The $U$-function may be [approximated](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.8.E14) in terms of Bessel functions as follows:
\begin{align*}
U\!\left( { - n,\frac{1}{2},\frac{q}{4}{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} } \right) & \sim ( - 1)^n {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i/4}} \left( {\frac{q}{{4n}}} \right)^{1/4} {\rm e}^{ - q/8} n!J_{ - 1/2} ({\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i/2}} \sqrt {nq} ) \\ & = ( - 1)^n \left( {\frac{q}{{4n}}} \right)^{1/4} {\rm e}^{ - q/8} n!I_{ - 1/2} (\sqrt {nq} )
\end{align*}
as $n\to +\infty$ for any fixed positive $q$. Using Stirling's formula and the known large argument [asymptotics](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30.E4) of the $I$ Bessel function then yields
$$
S(q,n) \sim \frac{{2^{n - 1} }}{{(\pi n)^{1/4} }}\exp \left( {\sqrt {nq}  - \frac{q}{8}} \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ for any fixed positive $q$.

For your related sum the above gives
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^n q^{n-k} \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!} \sim \frac{{(2q)^n }}{{2(\pi n)^{1/4} }}\exp\! \bigg( \sqrt {\frac{n}{q}}  - \frac{1}{{8q}} \bigg)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ for any fixed positive $q$. The treshold is at $q=\frac{1}{2}$ and your sum diverges if $q \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Your numerics with $q=3$ must have some error in it (or you mixed up $3$ and $\frac{1}{3}$).

Comment: Very nice. It is funny, beause when you expand $A^k f$ (defined in my question), the related sum is with $q = 1/2$, exactly at the treshold.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you ended up with $U\!\left( { - n,\frac{1}{2},\frac{q}{4}{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} } \right)$? Sorry for the naive question.

Comment: @bob Use the cited formula $(13.2.7)$ together with $$
\Gamma\! \left( {s + \frac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{{(2s)!}}{{4^s s!}}\sqrt \pi  .
$$

Comment: @Gary. I see how you used the formulas now, but how did you transform the sum into a form where the hypergeometric function can be applied?

Comment: @bob I have just told you. I don't see what else can be said.

Comment: @Gary. I ask this because I used the result from Wolfram, $$\sum_{k = 0}^n q^k \frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{(2k)!(n -k)!}=\frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{n!}{}_1F_1(-n;1/2;-q/4)$$then applied the formulas you provided. I am wondering how you come up with those parameters. Sorry for the confusion.